# Как передать массив на вход модуля в языке Verilog

Tags: массивы, verilog

Пишу программу на Verilog, мне нужно передать массив в модуль. Но напрямую передавать массив в модуль на языке Verilog нельзя. Как тогда это можно сделать? Какие есть ещё способы?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369698/how-to-pass-array-structure-between-two-verilog-modules

Comment: @eanmos Спасибо!